# How can I make script for multiple enemies

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a player combat script. but´its only works for 1 specific enemy. how can I make it multiple? here is the some part of my code.

```
[SerializeField]
private Enemy enemysc;
 
void Attack()
{
    if (attack2 == false && attack3 == false)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isAttack", true);
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);
        foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            enemysc.DamageEnemy(attackDamage); //(this part important for me)
 
        }
        attack2 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code above, you have an Enemy field and you are probably dragging one Enemy to the field on the editor. So it works for only one Enemy. There are lots of methods to do what you want depending on how your scene works, but one simplest way is to add a Tag to your Enemy prefab, call it "Enemy", then get them dynamically in your scripts by using a function like [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). This will give you all prefabs tagged as "Enemy" that are currently active on the screen. You can iterate through them to find which one you are fighting.

Another method, as you already know what GameObject you hit in your script. If your character is meant to hit different stuff, tag them with relevant tags and check the tag of the GameObject when you hit them. This way you can tell if you are hitting an enemy, ally, boxes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are just working with the "Enemy" object (Is it a Script?) And doing nothing with your foreach since you never use the "enemy" Collider2D in your loop, rendering the foreach useless. If "enemysc" is a script attached to your enemies you need to reach it with

```
enemy.gameObject.GetComponent<enemysc>().DamageEnemy(attackDamage);
```

Inside your loop. This might work if you are linking your script in the editor, but otherwise you can initialize it first making your script and DamageEnemy() **public** public via

```
Enemy enemysc = new Enemy();
```

and then use it the same way in the loop as above.

I don't know for sure how your "Enemy" object works, but using the Collider2D.gameObject inside your loop will get every enemy contained in your Collider2D array